# Horisontal HTML table with vertical data

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, html-table

I have been struggling to create a html table(I also use bootstrap). To make it easier to understand what I want to achieve, see picture below.

https://s15.postimg.org/ulq2gxap7/Hiro_Table.jpg

Depending on how many elements(lets say cars), the user selects, I want to create a column for each car. I have an array with the id of the selected itmes.

For now I do like this:

```
For(selected){
//get data from my object with id
.....

$('table thead tr').append(html);  
$('table tbody').append(htmlData);
}
```

Which outputs:

-----car1-------------car2--------------car3

---

----1911-------------Italian------------Red

----1923 ------------Italian------------Yellow

----1923  -----------Swedish------------Green

I want as the picture I link to.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't supplied the full HTML and JS code but basically between each TR with three TDs you need to append tr with td that have collspan=3

for example:

```css
table td {
  border: 1px solid #CCC;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="3">italian</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Fiat</td>
    <td>Ferarri</td>
    <td>1992</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="3">German</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>BMW</td>
    <td>VW</td>
    <td>Mercedes</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: I will be using the colspan :) but from the output of your code, the td's is still displayed horizontally. I would like all the attributes of the car to be displayed on top of each other(in order to be able to compare data side by side). So the TR as "header" and tds under each tr. I can update my code with html and javascript if it helps.

Comment: I think I found a solution, here is the fiddle, https://jsfiddle.net/proabid/04rebu95/2/ 
With css I was able to show the data vertically. How can I use colspan in this fiddle?

Comment: But now I cant add colspan  properly:/